# Log4Net Date and Time Without Leading Zeros (Conversion Pattern)

Tags: log4j, log4net

Does anyone know how to specify the date format so that leading zeros do not appear in the log?  I know it sounds very picky, but another process is reading my logs and seems not to like leading zeros.

I am using:

```
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="NamespaceName.ClassName" />
    </filter>     
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />   
    <param name="RemoteAddress" value="192.168.1.123" />
    <param name="RemotePort" value="514" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt} %message %newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And I get this:

07/10/2012 09:20:39 AM ...

If possible, I'd like to get:

7/10/2012 9:20:39 AM

I tried simply using: %date{M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}
But it didn't work (and also seems odd for when two chars are needed)

Edit on 07/15/12:

I am not yet back at the office so I haven't checked on the UDP bug yet, but in case anyone else out there wants to extend an appender simply to add a property to pass into your app:

```
public class SyslogAppender : UdpAppender
{
    public string UpdateIp { get; set; }

    // ReSharper disable RedundantOverridenMember
    override protected void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        base.Append(loggingEvent);

    }
    // ReSharper restore RedundantOverridenMember

}

<appender name="UdpAppender" type="Namespace.Log4Net.SyslogAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="Namespace.LogGenFileReparser" />
    </filter>  
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="Namespace.Log4Net.SyslogAppender" />
    </filter>       
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />   
    <param name="RemoteAddress" value="192.168.73.133" />
    <param name="RemotePort" value="514" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt} %message %newline" />
    </layout>
    <param name="UpdateIp" value="false" />
</appender>
```

I check the new param before calling configure:

```
        var log4FileConfigFile = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("log4net.config"));
        var firstOrDefault = log4FileConfigFile.Descendants("log4net").Descendants("appender").
            Select(appender => appender.Attributes().
                FirstOrDefault(attrib => attrib.Name == "name" && attrib.Value == "UdpAppender")).
                    FirstOrDefault(check => null != check);

        if (firstOrDefault != null)
            if (firstOrDefault.Document != null)
            {
                var xAttribute2 = firstOrDefault.Document.Descendants("param").
                    Attributes().FirstOrDefault(attrib => attrib.Value == "UpdateIp");

                if (xAttribute2 != null && xAttribute2.Value.ToLower().Equals("true"))
                {
                    var xAttribute = firstOrDefault.Document.Descendants("param").
                        Attributes().FirstOrDefault(attrib => attrib.Value == "RemoteAddress");
                    if (xAttribute != null)
                        xAttribute.NextAttribute.SetValue(
                            IPAddresses.GetLocalIp().ToString());
                }
            }

    XmlConfigurator.Configure(...
```

Edit 7/17/12

I had no other log4net error (with UDP appender).  The problem was in the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me but I'm logging to a file.

Are you sure whatever you are using the view the log isn't re-formatting the output?

Comment: Hmm.  I feel silly.  It seems to work for me, too.  I must have another problem with the process that is reading my UPD (syslog) appender.  Thanks for the verification.  I am not sure what I was doing the other day.